# How to check if an address is a validator?

Tags: validator

Is there a way to tell if a given Polkadot's address can be used in a nomination transaction? (aka if it's a validator)

It seems like the chain itself doesn't perform any checks and one can nominate to any account on the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can check if it is a key in the `Validators` storage map.